# How to sum records of a single column with different possibilities?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have an mysql query:

```
SELECT count(*) as `present_days` 
FROM  tbl_intime_status 
WHERE employee_status = 'Out' and 
      present_status = 'Full Day' and 
      date LIKE '%/"+month2+"/"+year1+"' and 
      employee_id="+ EmpId+
```

From this query I am getting no. of `Full Day` present.

I have `present_status= 'Half Day'` & `present_status = 'Full Day'` in my database records.

How to count 'Full Day' + 'Half Day'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the counts separate you can do this

```
SELECT present_status, count(*) as `present_days` 
FROM  tbl_intime_status 
WHERE employee_status = 'Out' and 
      present_status IN ('Full Day','Half Day')
      date LIKE '%/"+month2+"/"+year1+"' and 
      employee_id="+ EmpId+
GROUP BY present_status
```

If you want the total of both do this

```
SELECT count(*) as `present_days` 
FROM  tbl_intime_status 
WHERE employee_status = 'Out' and 
      present_status IN ('Full Day','Half Day')
      date LIKE '%/"+month2+"/"+year1+"' and 
      employee_id="+ EmpId+
```

Answer (score 3):

try, don'tforget to escape the `date` column since it is a reserved word.

```
SELECT present_status, count(*) as `present_days` 
FROM   tbl_intime_status 
WHERE  employee_status = 'Out' and 
       present_status IN ('Full Day','Half Day')
       `date` LIKE '%/"+month2+"/"+year1+"' and 
       employee_id = " + EmpId + "
GROUP BY present_status
```

Answer (score 2):

I want to try this to see if it works:

```
...

present_status in ('Full Day',  'Half Day' )

...
```

The grammar can be found here : [**SQL IN Operator.**](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Just add it to your where clause, either with `IN`:

```
...
WHERE present_status IN ('Full Day','Half Day')
...
```

or with `OR`:

```
...
WHERE (present_status = 'Full Day' OR present_status = 'Half Day')
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
SELECT count(*) as present_days 
FROM tbl_intime_status 
WHERE employee_status = 'Out' 
and present_status IN ('Full Day', 'Half Day') 
and date LIKE '%/"+month2+"/"+year1+"' 
and employee_id="+ EmpId
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you split up of all types of counts in one row:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(present_status  = 'Full Day', 1, 0)) AS full_present_days,
       SUM(IF(present_status  = 'Half Day', 1, 0)) AS half_present_days,
       COUNT(*) AS present_days
FROM  tbl_intime_status
WHERE employee_status = 'Out' and
      present_status IN('Full Day', 'Half Day') and
      date LIKE '%/"+month2+"/"+year1+"' and
      employee_id="+ EmpId+;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SUM(
   CASE present_status
     WHEN 'Full Day' THEN 1
     WHEN 'Half Day' THEN 0.5
     END
 ) as `present_days`  
FROM  tbl_intime_status  WHERE employee_status = 'Out'
```

Hope this is the query you are looking for.